# Angular 2+ print manually ngx print

Tags: angular, printing

I need to print a `div` using `ngx-print` in Angular +2, but send it manually, not as button attribute `ngxPrint`

```
<button printSectionId="print-section" (click)="printProcedure()">print</button> 

    printProcedure(){    
         /* DO SOME STUFF*/  
        //Print out after validations   
        ngxPrint.print() 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use the ngx-print pack. You can only do this with JS like this.

```
 printProcedure(innerHtml: any) {
    const mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'width=1023,height=1000');
    mywindow.document.write(`
    <html>
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <style type="text/css">
          @page {
            page-break-after: always;
            margin: 2cm 1cm;
          }

          pre {
            font-size: 20px;
            border: 0;
            margin-top: -130px;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>${innerHTML}</body>
    </html>`);
    mywindow.document.close();
    mywindow.focus();
    setTimeout(() => {
      mywindow.print();
      mywindow.close();
    }, 400);
}
```